# GCP cloudbuild deploy to Compute Engine running linux

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-cloud-source-repos

I am trying to use cloudbuild.yaml to deploy jar file built using maven to GCP compute engine linux VM and I am not able to find a solution.No steps available in GCP documentation.
I am able to deploy the jar to GCP bucket but not to VM

steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package']

artifacts:

- objects:

  - location: 'gs://<>/target'
    paths: ['target/abcd.jar']

What should be the Artifact location for GCP compute Engine ?